# python multiline does not work with / operator

Tags: python

```
rectified_mean_quad_error = (sum_quad_error - sum(quad_error_outliers))/(number_of_quads - len(quad_error_outliers))
```

The above code work alright in python

However, if I try to break the above statement into two lines using the '/' operator and adjust the indent, it does not work. I don't know why this is the case because I have used multiline with '+'without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

To have broken line in Python you need to have open parenthesis:

```
rectified_mean_quad_error = ((sum_quad_error - sum(quad_error_outliers))/
    (number_of_quads - len(quad_error_outliers)))
```

or use `\` to break:

```
rectified_mean_quad_error = (sum_quad_error - sum(quad_error_outliers))/  \
    (number_of_quads - len(quad_error_outliers))
```

Answer (score 1):

While zch's answer is completely correct (I gave it a +1, and you should accept it), the idiomatic way to solve this problem is to break up the statement:

```
quad_sum_diff = sum_quad_error - sum(quad_error_outliers)
quad_count = number_of_quads - len(quad_error_outliers)
rectified_mean_quad_error = quad_sum_diff / quad_count
```

This allows you to give nice names to the intermediate results (I just guessed at the names, but presumably you actually know what they're supposed to mean), which generally makes things much more readable than an expression that goes on for 2 lines and scrolls off the right end of the window.

Answer (score 0):

To separate something like this into multiple lines, you'll need to insert a `\`, so it will look something like:

```
rectified_mean_quad_error = (sum_quad_error - sum(quad_error_outliers)) / \
                            (number_of_quads - len(quad_error_outliers))
```